# Haskell Multiset Operations

Tags: haskell, union, intersect, multiset

I am trying to create functions which can find the union and intersection of two multi sets in Haskell without the use of the Multiset module. I have a good understanding of basic intersections and unions in normal lists but multisets seem to throw me. So far for the intersect function I have:

```
setUnique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
setUnique [] = []
setUnique (x:xs)
    | elem x xs = setUnique xs
    | otherwise = x : setUnique xs

setIntersect' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
setIntersect' xs ys = setUnique (xs ++ ys)
```

The issue I have in the above code is that I am actually getting values that aren't a part of the intersect. eg [1,2,2,3,3,3] [1,2,2] = [3,1,2]

Comment: Intersection of `[1,1,2,2]` with itself would be again `[1,1,2,2]`. I don't think `setUnique` would be very useful in computing the intersection, or in calculations with multisets in general.

Comment: `setIntersect'` is just reducing the union of two multisets to its underlying set.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the values because

```
xs ++ ys
```

has all elements ([1,2,2,3,3,3] ++ [1,2,2] = [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2])

and setUnique is just removing the extras

```
setUnique [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,2] = [3,1,2]
```

I think you want to use something other than (++) here (this is what you will want for Union, you will need to write something for intersect).